# How to render latex in-line with org mode?

Tags: org-mode, latex

I have a file with the following contents:

```
Math Notes -*- mode: org -*-
#+STARTUP: latexpreview

Test $\forall \epsilon > 0$
```

I am trying to render the latex with C-c C-x C-l, but it's not working. My .emacs.d file is taken straight from [this gh repo](https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d).
Could someone please offer some advise on how to debug this? Thanks!